# A more efficient way to hide/show divs using PHP?

Tags: php, html

As a form of user permissions I am hiding and showing content using if statements to test the user's 'authority' level. In this example, if their level is 2, they can view the content. I was wondering if there was a more efficient way to do what I have attempted as this seems a little clunky?

```php
<?php
    if($userType==2){
?>
<form action="" method="post">
    <b> Update group information. </b>
    <label for="groupdesc">Group Description</label>
    <input type="text" rows="3" name="groupdesc" id="groupdesc" value="<?php echo $groupDesc; ?>">
</form>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: i can think of 6 dozen ways of doing it, but if it works ...

Comment: Thanks, i'm really new to php so I don't want to put a bunch of security flaws into this project. But like you said, if it works.

Comment: @user3642576, the only real security concern is with how you're retrieving `$userType`. If you're using `SQL` and doing your `INSERT`s and `UPDATE`s securely/correctly, then getting the `$userType` from your database, then there's nothing to worry about. A simple `if() else if () ...` is plenty efficient, but it can make code difficult to read sometimes.

Comment: the original question did not mention security just "efficiency"

Answer (score 0):

You could use a switch statement to do this but i am not sure what you are trying to achieve. Writing plain php is ok to learn but you should learn to encapsulate your app into a framework or build a delivery system for that "view" - html depending on the user access level.

Here's my 2 cents on what i can understand you need:

```
<?php
switch($userType) {
    case 1:
     ?><div>use class 1</div><?php
    break;
    case 2:
     ?><div>use class 2</div><?php
    break;
    case 3:
     ?><div>use class 3</div><?php
    break;
    default:
     ?><div>You are not authorized to view this</div><?php
    break;
}
```